# Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 3000 v2.0 doesnt recognize "Flip Key"

Tags: keyboard

The Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 3000 v2.0 has a new key called a "flip key" where the right windows button should be (to the right of the right alt key).

This is a picture, the key in question is called "Windows Flip":
http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/digital-media-keyboard-3000#details

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and this key is not recognized at all by the system: I have run "sudo showkey"
with no results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I would like to map this to be a Right-Super key as it should be.

Comment: leave it to MS to figure something out that only they can use

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same keyboard, and i noticed that the events for these special keys are sent to /dev/usb/hiddev0.
So i started making a tool for reading them. It's still in early stage, but working.
You can find it here: http://github.com/rockman81/Touche